# Magento Extension Fatal Error "EaDesign_PdfGenerator"

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, fatal-error, extensions

I installed EaDesign_PdfGenerator on my Magento Version 1.9.1.0 with the Magento Connect Manager succesfully ( with no error message ).
But if I entered the Backend it says:

> Fatal error: Class 'EaDesign_PdfGenerator_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/app/Mage.php on line 547

I think I am not using the new "rwd" Theme if this is important.

On my other Magento installation there is no problem by using this plugin (there I am using the rwd theme)

Code of my adminhtml.xml of the plugin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <pdfadmin_menu>
            <title>EaDesign PDF</title>
            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
            <children>
                <first_page>
                    <title>Templates</title>
                    <action>adminpdfgenerator/adminhtml_pdfgenerator</action>
                </first_page>
            </children>
        </pdfadmin_menu>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <pdfadmin_menu>
                        <title>EaDesign PDF</title>
                        <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <!-- child items go here -->
                            <first_page>
                                <title>Templates</title>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            </first_page>
                        </children>
                    </pdfadmin_menu>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: did you clear the cache? did you disable the compilation?

Comment: i disabled the cache and  i cant clear it afterwards but the installation with magento connect cleared the cache automatically.

Comment: Did you already contact EaDesign?

Comment: i did about the board magento itself and via mail.

Answer (score 2):

That means there is no `data.php` in your installed extension.

Check `EaDesign/PdfGenerator/Helper/Data.php`

If it does not exist create one with following code:

```
<?php
class EaDesign_PdfGenerator_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Comment: wow, fast answer here ;) thanks. Im going to try this.

Comment: the class already exists in /httpdocs/app/code/local/EaDesign/PdfGenerator/Helper/Data.php

Comment: try disabling this extension from `mage/etc/modules/EaDesign***.xml` by setting `active to false` and see if this is the extension causing it.

Comment: if i deinstall the app via magento connect manager (by routing directly in /downloader) the error is gone.

Comment: @MCSell If it already exists, then your issue is most likely either cache or compilation (or EaDesign have a bug in their configs). Try clearing the cache manually by emptying the var/cache/ directory of Magento.

Comment: ive done this <active>false</active> and the problem were still there. I deleted the cache manually with and the error was gone. I tried it with <active>true</active> deleted cache again and the error is there again.

Comment: I guess your `system.xml` or `adminhtml.xml` if you have any of these in `etc` folder are causing the issue. Try to open these files and check if there are any `tag` says `module or translate`, then just remove those and see if that helps. and obviously clean cache.

Comment: thanks there were both of the tags in `adminhtml.xml` the admin backend is working againd but if i go in the tab of the plugin it says `Fatal error: Class 'EaDesign_PdfGenerator_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/app/Mage.php on line 547`

Comment: can you paste that code here of `adminhtml.xml`.

Comment: postet code in question directly.

Comment: Your qst is already on hold since being off topic, still last time I would suggest you to delete from `<acl> to </acl>` in `adminhtml.xml` and see if that helps. Otherwise you should report this bug to developer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try this. Is there a way, that i can put it "on topic" again? :) add some infos or something?